# I have no clue why the data is visible in url? Whenever I login the email and password is shown in url . Don't know why

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After login url is shown as `"http://localhost:3000/login?email=m%40gmail.com&password=567"`. I do not want the credentials to be visible in the url. I have written login function in different js file and accessed it into dashboard component and then sent it through props in login component.

Here is my code for Login component

```
const [fields, errors, form] = useFormInputValidation(
  {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  },
  {
    email: "required|email",
    password: "required",
  }
);

var loginFunc = (event) => {
  //debugger;
  const isValid = form.validate(event);
  props.login(fields,isValid);
}

return (
  <div>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div className="card mt-5">
            <div className="card-header text-center">
              <h4>Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              <form
                onSubmit={() => {
                  // debugger;
                  loginFunc();
                  // navigate("/");
                }}
              >
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label for="username">UserName:</label> 
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="email"
                    name="email" 
                    onBlur={form.handleBlurEvent}
                    onChange={form.handleChangeEvent}
                    value={fields.email}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group mt-2">
                  <label for="password">Password:</label>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    onBlur={form.handleBlurEvent}
                    onChange={form.handleChangeEvent}
                    value={fields.password}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group mt-3">
                  <Link to={"/forgotPassword"}>Forgot password</Link>
                </div>
                        
                <div>
                  <center>
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn btn-primary btn-block my-3"
                    >
                      Sign In
                    </button>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </form>
              <div className="text-center mt-3">
                Don't have an account?<Link to={"/register"}>Sign Up</Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Dashboard Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Home/Home'
import Login from './Login'
import Header from './Header'
import Registration from './Register';
import About from './About';
import Footer from './Footer';
import ForgotPassword from './forgotPassword';
import Helper from './Helper';

export default function Dashboard() {
  var { isLoggedIn, clearStorage, getSessionStorage, login } = Helper();
  // var navigate = useNavigate();
  var [uName, setUName] = useState("Guest");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
      var loggedInUserName = getSessionStorage("userName");
      setUName(loggedInUserName);
    }
  }, []);

  var UpdateHeader = (userName) => {
    setUName(userName);
  }

  var signOut = () => {
    setUName("Guest");
    clearStorage();
    // navigate("/");
  }

  var signIn = () => {
    // navigate("/login");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div className="home_div">
          <Header signOut={signOut} /> 
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login login={login} />} />
            {/* <Route exact path="/login" element={Login} /> */}
            <Route exact path="/register" element={<Registration />} />
            {/* <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route path='/admin/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
            </Route> */}
            <Route exact path="/forgotPassword" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Below is login function

```js
var login = (fields, isValid) => {
  // debugger;
  //var navigate = useNavigate();
  //const isValid = await form.validate(event);
  if (isValid) {
    axios.post("http://localhost:7070/FP/users/login", {
      email: fields.email,
      password: fields.password
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        //.push("/login")
        if (fields.email == response.data.email
          && fields.password == response.data.password
        ) { 
          setSessionStorage("userName", response.data.firstName);
          setSessionStorage("user", response.data);
          setSessionStorage("isLoggedIn", true);
          setSessionStorage("token", "1234");
          window.alert("Logged in as " + response.data.firstName);
          //navigate("/");
          console.log(response); 
        } else {
          window.alert("Credentials do not match");
        }
        console.log(response);  
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });   
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Login component's jsx, you'll have to stop the native form submission.
You can do it like this:

```
<form
    onSubmit={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault(); // <- this will stop the url from changing.
      loginFunc(); 
}}>
...
```